# Reset a webp animation so that it will play from frame 1, restart animated webp

Tags: animation, reset, webp

This issue has been discussed for gif files.
Here is what DID NOT WORK for webp files. Script starts with,

```
var animatedWebpImg = document.getElementById('idOfTheWebpInsideAnImgElement');
```

First failed attempt was,

```
animatedWebpImg.style.display = "none";
setTimeout(function() {  animatedWebpImg.style.display = "block";  },100);
```

Second, I have tried `removeChild()` and `appendChild()` with exactly the same logic but that didn't work either.

Finally I got close however without success,

```
var srcOfTheImg = animatedWebpImg.src;
animatedWebpImg.src = "";                 // empty and then back to original
animatedWebpImg.src = srcOfTheImg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked,

```
var srcOfTheImg = animatedWebpImg.src;
animatedWebpImg.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==";
setTimeout(function () {  animatedWebpImg.src = srcOfTheImg;  },100);
```

That means, instead of emptying the src to nothing, I had to fill it with a transparent pixel - an invisible something.

Comment: using `animatedWebpImg.src = "";` also worked for me, the timeout seems to be the key.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old but I tried to use the solution and couldn't, here's the way I found to perform the restart.

```
$(myElement).html(`<img src='mySource.webp?v=${Math.random()}'/>`);
```